# How to test a method which creates a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, junit4, executorservice

This is the first time I am attempting to write JUnit for a multithreading java program.

I have a method which looks like below, can you please suggest how I can write the JUnit for that? or point to any such similar examples? Thanks much in advance...!!

```
public void myMethod(Input input) {
    if (!this.isStreamingPaused()) {
        ExecutorService publisherThreadPool = getThreadPool();
        PublisherThread publisher = new PublisherThread();
        publisher.setInputData(input);
        publisherThreadPool.execute(publisher);
        publisherThreadPool.shutdown();
    }
}

public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
    final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new BasicThreadFactory.Builder()
                .namingPattern("MyName-%d")
                .priority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
                .build();
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, threadFactory);
}
```

Comment: Separate your concerns.  As the name implies, unit tests should target units of functionality.  Try one test for the class that spawns the thread and a second test for the thread class itself.

Comment: Thanks EJK for replying. I am going to write separate junit for main functionality in PublisherThread thread, but I am concerned here that how I can test, that code block inside myMethod which is generating the thread?

Comment: Note that creating the thread pool like that means that you can't execute `myMethod` more than once. You might also want to check if the executor has been shut down, and also create a new instance in that case.

Comment: Why `publisherThreadPool.shutdown()` after `execute` knowing that `getThreadPool()` returns the same instance, you won't be able to call `myMethod` twice, is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, It is expected behaviour that myMethod will not be executed multiple times until 1 thread is over. This code is written in a way that only 1 thread should be publishing data at any time. If there is another data record ready for publish while a thread is already running and publishing (single or multiple data)  data, then it writes the data to  Queue/buffer.

Comment: We actually don't need multiple threading, but in our case job of data publish takes few seconds to get complete and it was making this method call a blocking one. So just to get this publishing task running parallelly without blocking other tasks we have written code which will be running parallel on a single thread

Comment: what are `PublisherThread` and `Input`?

Comment: Input is a java class which has data, timestamp, source info etc and PublisherThread has code which utilizes the external libraries(Kafka) which transmits the data to particular topics and some consumers will consume that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a  `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`

```
public void myMethod(Input input) {
    if (!this.isStreamingPaused()) {
        ExecutorService publisherThreadPool = getThreadPool();

        // in case that you'd have more of the same kind of operations to do
        // you can use appropriately a higher count than 1
        CountDownLatch  latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        PublisherThread publisher = new PublisherThread();
        publisher.setInputData(input);
        publisherThreadPool.execute(publisher);
        publisherThreadPool.shutdown();


        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.info("Interrupted by another thread");
        } 
    }
}
```

In your `PublisherThread` class you do these changes:

```
private CountDownLatch latch;

public PublisherThread(CountDownLatch latch){
    this.latch = latch;
}

public void run(){
  try{
      // kafka business logic
      // ....
  } finally {
      // you don't want your program to hang in case of an exception 
      // in your business logic
      latch.countDown();
  }
}
```